# Ng-Style Conditional Operators not working Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

**UPDATED**

```
 <div style="margin-top: 10px; color: white; height: 50%; padding: 5%; font-size: 25px; font-weight: bold"
    [ngStyle]="{'background-color': global.timeSpent <= '10' ? 'LimeGreen' : ((global.timeSpent > '10' && global.timeSpent <= '20')  ? 'Gold' : 'Red' ) }">{{global.timeSpent}}</div>
```

**Second Approch**

```
<div [ngStyle]="styleColor"> {{global.timeSpent}}</div>                   
styleColor(){
this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance = this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance.split('%')[0]

if(this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance <= '10') {
return  '{ "background-color": "LimeGreen" }';
}
else if(this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance > '10' && this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance <= '20'){
return  '{ "background-color": "Gold"}';
}
else{ 
return '{ "background-color": "Crimson" }';
}
```

}

Conditions are not working properly. I thinnk '**<=**' operator is not working properly because IDE showing **<** sign in red and rest in blue even > sign is also in blue color.

What is wrong here?

Comment: `ngStyle` is a angular `attribute` to an element

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: you mean updated question

Comment: by the way what makes you use `<=` with `string`?

Comment: @manish  removed quotes

Comment: it should work then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using too many quote marks.
Is `global` a variable in your component? If so then try this:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color': global.timeSpent <= 0.1 ? 'LimeGreen' : ((global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance > 0.1 && global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance <= 0.2)  ? 'Gold' : 'Crimson' ) }"
```

I changed your '10%' to 0.1, because i'm assuming you want to compare a number not a string. The gist is that you shouldn't wrap things that aren't strings in quotes.

Though, you definitely shouldn't be doing all that in the html. pull it into your component as a function and then reference it like `[ngStyle]="getStyle()"` or something like that. Much cleaner.

Comment: what is ‘global.timeSpent’? is it a number? you can’t compare a number to a string with ‘<‘ either needs to be 10 or 0.1, not ‘10’ or ‘10%’

Comment: then remove the quotes from it and it should work. does that make sense?

Comment: Banging head with walls :'( why I was giving it as a string.. thanks :p

Answer (score 1):

The ngStyle have to be inside the div. In your code the div is closed. Please see below:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':global.timeSpent <= '10' ? 'LimeGreen' : ((global.timeSpent > '10' && global.timeSpent <= '20')  ? 'Gold' : 'Crimson' ) }">{{global.timeSpent}} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since the html code getting so convoluted. try to move the logic to component class

```
get styleColor(){

  if(this.global.timeSpent <= '10%') return  '{ "background-color": "LimeGreen" }';
  if(this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance > '10%' && this.global.timeSpentToStoryPointVariance <= '20%') return  '{ "background-color": "Gold"}';
  return '{ "background-color": "Crimson" }';
}
```

call the property from the style

```
<div [ngStyle]="styleColor"
```